# login hang after password

Tags: 12.04, updates, do-release-upgrade

I'm new to Ubuntu and was running updates from 12.04 to 14.04 when some system error showed up and I restarted. But now after typing the password it refuses to log in and just hangs.

*What should I do?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try to change to the main TTY terminal by pressing [Ctrl] [Alt] and [F1],
This takes you to TTY0 where you type in your loginname and [Enter]
Now you are asked for your password - type that in (beware it dosn't show your password, so you are typing blind.
Now run sudo apt-get autoclean
 - sudo apt-get autoremowe.
refresh the packetcash by running:
 - sudo apt-get update
upgrade your system with:
 - sudo apt-get upgrade.
after it finnishes you can get back to the GUI by this command
 - chvt 7
Best of luck.

Comment: Ok I got till the autoremove but when I type the update thing, I get :-: command not found

Comment: Sorry thats 2 commands 1: sudo apt-get update - updates the pacakeges, and sudo apt-get upgrade - sor the actual upgrade.