# Ubuntu 18.04 hangs after login page after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, login-screen

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS Zenbook UX303L. After installing nvadia graphics and rebooting I can't get past the login page after entering my credentials.

I used these commands to install nvidia graphics driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

Here are some of the solutions I have tried.

1) Get into TTY terminal and reinstalling nvidia graphics drivers. I am unable to do that because of these error [Output when I try to debug via TTY.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjQIK.jpg) I am basically helpless on TTY as I can't execute anything.

[login hang after password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/570871/login-hang-after-password)

2) Installed Ubuntu and Nvidia drivers
on the GRUB page, pressed **E** and added `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line and F10.

3) I loaded older kernel version using the advanced option on GRUB menu. I still get stuck after login screen.

Still no luck. Right now I am confused if its my graphics or kernel. Any idea what should I do? Any help will be appreciated.

Also here is my system info (I got this by booting using USB cus I didn't wanna reinstall Ubuntu.)

> `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ inxi -Fx
>   System:    Host: ubuntu Kernel: 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.2 
>              Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver) 
>   Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: UX303LNB v: 1.0 serial: <root required> 
>              Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX303LNB v: 1.0 serial: <root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: UX303LNB.203 
>              date: 12/10/2014 
>   Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 22.9 Wh condition: 40.3/50.1 Wh (80%) model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery status: Discharging 
>   CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-5500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
>              flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19154 
>              Speed: 1400 MHz min/max: 500/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1400 2: 1397 3: 1397 4: 1397 
>   Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
>              Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 840M] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nouveau v: kernel bus ID: 03:00.0 
>              Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nouveau resolution: 3200x1800~60Hz 
>              Message: Unable to show advanced data. Required tool glxinfo missing. 
>   Audio:     Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
>              Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
>              bus ID: 00:1b.0 
>              Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-29-generic 
>   ^ANetwork:   Device-1: Intel Wireless 7265 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: f040 bus ID: 02:00.0 
>              IF: wlp2s0 state: down mac: 60:57:18:3d:ed:0c 
>              Device-2: ASIX AX88772B type: USB driver: asix bus ID: 1-3:6 
>              IF: enx9cebe81d1999 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 9c:eb:e8:1d:19:99 
>   Drives:    Local Storage: total: 503.04 GiB used: 406.9 MiB (0.1%) 
>              ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HGST (Hitachi) model: HTS545050B7E660 size: 465.76 GiB 
>              ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Kingston model: SMSM150S324G2 size: 22.37 GiB 
>              ID-3: /dev/sdc type: USB vendor: SanDisk model: Cruzer Switch size: 14.91 GiB 
>   Partition: ID-1: / size: 3.85 GiB used: 406.9 MiB (10.3%) fs: overlay source: ERR-102 
>   Sensors:   Missing: Required tool sensors not installed. Check --recommends 
>   Info:      Processes: 221 Uptime: 8m Memory: 7.70 GiB used: 1.25 GiB (16.2%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A 
>              Shell: bash v: 4.4.19 inxi: 3.0.30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with setting up NVIDIA graphics with proprietary drivers:

1. Go to https://www.geforce.com/drivers and download latest Linux 64-bit
   drivers for your GPU (Pick the latest one, 410.93 being the latest
   as am writing)
2. Reboot your Laptop in recovery mode (In the GRUB
   screen, press 'e' and add '1' to the line that starts with linux, it
   should 2nd line from the bottom) and press 'F10'
3. Enter the root password
4. Make sure there is no 'xorg.conf' under '/etc/X11/' folder
5. Go to the directory where you have downloaded the latest NVIDIA driver
6. Run the NVIDIA driver installer as 'sh ./NVIDIA-xxxxx.run' and follow the instructions
7. Edit the file with 'sudo nano /etc/initramfs-tools/modules' and add the following modules in separate lines: nvidia, nvidia_modeset, nvidia_uvm, nvidia_drm
8. Run 'sudo update-initramfs -c -k all'
9. Add the kernel parameter 'nvidia-drm.modeset=1' in the file '/etc/default/grub' to the line that starts with "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"
10. Run 'sudo update-grub'
11. Reboot the Laptop into Linux normally

If you run into compilation problems, look into the NVIDIA installer logs for exact errors. In most cases, you may need to install the 'linux-headers' (corresponding to your linux kernel version), 'gcc' packages and then retry the NVIDIA driver installation.